# Find the probability generating function

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, generating-functions

I have an exercise of this type that I just can not solve

"Are $x$ and $y$ be independent random variables, $X$-Poisson($a$), $Y$-Poisson($b$). Find the probability generating function of the random variable $z = 2x+3y+4$"

help me :(

The only thing I could do is to put into practice a property of the probability generating function: 
$$G_z(u)= E(u^z) = E(u^{2x+3y+4}) = E(u^{2x} \cdot u^{3y} \cdot u^4) )= u^4 \cdot E(u^{2x}) \cdot E(u^{3y})$$

Comment: Have you tried anything? If you show us what you tried, it's easier to help

Comment: the only thing I could do is to put into practice a property of the probability generating function,

Comment: : Gz(u)= E(u^z) = E(u^2x+3y+4) = E(u^2x*u^3y*u^4) )= u^4*E(u^2x)*E(u^3y)

Comment: The expectation is linear, but you can't just multiply expected values!

Comment: @vonbrand: Why not? $X$ and $Y$ are independent, therefore so are $u^{2X}$ and $u^{2Y}$. In fact, that you can multiply expected values (of independent random variables) is AFAIK one of the main reasons for using probability/moment generating functions in the first place. :-)

Answer (score 1):

First you can find the probability generating function for a Poisson distribution.

If $X \sim \mathcal{P}(a)$ then :
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
E(t^X) & = & \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-a} \frac{a^n}{n!} t^n\\
& = & e^{-a} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(at)^n}{n!} \\
\Longleftrightarrow E(t^X) & = & e^{-a + at}
\end{array}
$$

You should now be able to find the probability generating function of Z with what you wrote :
$$E(t^Z) = t^4 E(t^{2X}) E(t^{3Y})$$
by substituting $t$ by $t^2$ and $t^3$ in the equation above.

You should find :
$$E(t^Z) = t^4e^{-a-b + at^2 + bt^3}$$

Comment: Be careful, you can't multiply expected values like that.

Comment: The expected value is indeed not linear, but in case of independent random variables $X$ and $Y$, one have $E(XY) = E(X)E(Y)$
Am I missing something ?